# changing the (new) "addyear" style option in "biblatex-dw"

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

Dear great LaTeX folks,

since recently, the great biblatex-dw-style offers the "addyear" option, providing the year after the title in citation short form - in parentheses.

Which means, after a first citation such as this:

> Marc Vogel: *Durch Technik gutzumachen, was Technik frevelte. Zur
>   Polivalenz der "Technik" bei Theodor W. Adorno*. Würzburg:
>   Königshausen und Neumann 2012 (= Epistemata Philosophie 508).
>
> Thorsten Ries: Vom Ende des Empedokles. In: *DVjs* 75.2 (2001), S.
>   251-287.

the next citation would be:

> Marc Vogel: *Durch Technik gutzumachen, was Technik frevelte* (2012),
>   S. x-y
>
> Thorsten Ries: Vom Ende des Empedokles (2001), S. x-y

In the Germanistik tradition of citing, the following would look a little more common:

> Marc Vogel: *Durch Technik gutzumachen, was Technik frevelte*. 2012,
>   S. x-y
>
> Thorsten Ries: Vom Ende des Empedokles. 2001, S. x-y

The period after the title can be achieved thu the following command:

```
\renewcommand*{\titleyeardelim}{.\addspace}
```

My question is: How can I get rid of the parentheses?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to redefine two macros of `authortitle-dw.cbx`.

Just add the following lines to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifsingletitle
    {\setunit{}}% Löschen des \nametitledelim, falls kein Titel ausgegeben wird
    {\ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifentrytype{review}}
      and
      not test {\iffieldundef{xref}}
    }
      {\printtext[review]{\bbx@review{\thefield{xref}}}}
      {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
         \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
     \ifbool{cbx:addyear}
        {\iffieldundef{year}
           {}
           {\titleyeardelim%
            \printfield{year}}}% no \parentext here
        {}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:title:force}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
  \ifbool{cbx:addyear}
    {\iffieldundef{year}
      {}
      {\titleyeardelim%
       \printfield{year}}}% no \parentext here
    {}}
\makeatother
```

One more thing: Instead of `\renewcommand*{\titleyeardelim}{.\addspace}` I would use the `biblatex` macros `\renewcommand*{\titleyeardelim}{\addperiod\addspace}`.

The MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  style=authortitle-dw,
  backend=biber,
  addyear=true,
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifsingletitle
    {\setunit{}}% Löschen des \nametitledelim, falls kein Titel ausgegeben wird
    {\ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifentrytype{review}}
      and
      not test {\iffieldundef{xref}}
    }
      {\printtext[review]{\bbx@review{\thefield{xref}}}}
      {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
         \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}%
     \ifbool{cbx:addyear}
        {\iffieldundef{year}
           {}
           {\titleyeardelim%
            \printfield{year}}}% no \parentext here
        {}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:title:force}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}%
  \ifbool{cbx:addyear}
    {\iffieldundef{year}
      {}
      {\titleyeardelim%
       \printfield{year}}}% no \parentext here
    {}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\titleyeardelim}{\addperiod\addspace}
\begin{document}
  \cite{wilde} and \cite{cicero} and \cite{wilde} and \cite{cicero}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields
[image]

Comment: Thx so much that was quick! I'll give this one a test drive right away! :-)